# Round Off Error Analysis

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

$x$ is a real number.
In analysing the round off error for the floating point computation $fl(x^n)$ of  $x^n$ for some positive integer $n$, I'm able to bound the error as:

$x^n(1 + d_{min})^{n-1} \le fl(x^n) \le x^n(1 + d_{max})^{n-1}$ where $d_{min} \lt d_{max}$

Intuitively, I can see that there must exist $d_{min} \le \alpha \le d_{max}$ such that $fl(x^n) = x^n(1+ \alpha)^{n-1}$

How do you formally prove that?

Comment: You can either directly compute $α$ or use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: You need to replace $n-1$ with $n$.  While there are $n-1$ multiplications which each introduce a term $(1+\delta_j)$, where $|\delta_j| \leq u$ and $u$ is the unit roundoff, you must not forget the initial error committed when the real number $x$ is replaced with its floating point representation.

Comment: @LutzL I initially directly computed $\alpha$. But using IVT is more concise. Thanks.

Comment: @CarlChristian My mistake, I had forgotten to mention that $x$ is a machine number. Thanks.